# ASP.NET MVC Submit button does not work on Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, form-submit, submit-button

The code below works perfectly on IE, but when used in Chrome, it doesn't work. When I checked in debug mode, it doesn't trigger the MVC controller (but in IE it does). Does anyone know how I can get this to work in Chrome?

```
 <input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnSaveSubmit" name="btnSubmit" class="button" onclick="if (!($('#frID').valid())) { return false; } this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Saving...'" />
```

Comment: Is there any chance the `return false` gets executed which is preventing the form submit ? Put an alert/console log before that and you can confirm it.

Comment: I tried what you said and it's not getting execute.

Comment: you mean the console/alert is not executing ? do you have any script error in your page ? (check console tab in your dev tools)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just pure html & Javascript, doesn't relate to mvc.

Anyway, Chrome does not allow you to execute inline code. [Inline JavaScript will not be executed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution)

Proper way to do:

1)With javascript: Bind the event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('btnSaveSubmit');
    // onClick's logic below:
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (!($('#frID').valid())){
            return false;
        }
        this.disabled = true;
        this.value = 'Saving...';
    });
});
```

2) With Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSaveSubmit).on('click',function(){

        if (!($('#frID').valid())){
            return false;
        }
        this.disabled = true;
        this.value = 'Saving...';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

encountered this issue in Chrome as well. The cause for me: I was disabling the submit button after it was being clicked.

For Chrome, but not other browsers, the click handler seems to fire before the submit handler. For that reason, I never got to back to the controller.

The solution for me was to not disable the submit button at all after the user clicked it.